# jQuery-File-Upload without file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file-upload, jquery-plugins

I'm using the jQuery plugin "jQuery-File-Upload" to manage a form I have. I've tried searching for my problem on google but nothing so far.

The problem is that this form allows an optional field for file upload. When I insert a file it all goes ok, but when I decide to not include a file the plugin script won't even run.

Now I know this is a plugin specifically to upload files, nevertheless it becomes rather inconvenient if we have to duplicate code just to provide an alternative AJAX call for submissions without files.

Is there a way to solve this issue?

Thanks
Peter

update to add code:

`form.fileupload
(
    {
        url               : 'php/file.php',
        dataType          : 'json',
        autoUpload        : false,
        replaceFileInput  : false,
        sequentialUploads : false,
        maxFileSize       : 10000000,
        minFileSize       : 0,
        acceptFileTypes   : /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
        add : function (e, data)
        {
            data.context = button.click
            (
                function (e)
                {
                    e.preventDefault ();
                    // PARSE DATA FOR VALIDATION
                    // OK TO SEND
                    data.submit();
                }
            );
        },
        fail : function (e, data)
        {
            console.log ('fail');
            console.log (data);
        },
        progressall : function (e, data)
        {
            console.log ('progress');
            console.log (progress);
        },
        done : function (e, data)
        {
            console.log ('done');
            console.log (data);
        }
    }
);`

Comment: Can you show the code you are using?

Comment: While I haven't solve the problem I realized that the plugin is only triggered once I click on the input file. Meaning that any function added to the "add" option is only triggered once you click on input file.

So when no file is added the submit button will just invoque the form submission if no preventDefault is declared.

It may not solve the problem of the empty file option but it certainty doesn't help on the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the response from the author saying this option is not implemented on the framework: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/issues/3105.

I decided to go with a different jQuery plugin http://malsup.com/jquery/form/ that doesn't force me to duplicate code for a form submission with or without file attached methods.
Works in IE9.